# Separate listening url and route url in AngularJS

Tags: angular

I have an angular site that is placed behind a proxy. This proxy strips of a part of the url and then forwards it to angular.

```
                    myurl.org/mysite/route/           localhost:12345/route/
Incoming request --------------------------> Proxy -------------------------> angular
```

Thus I'm in a situation of needing the webserver to listen on `localhost:12345`, but when constructing urls i need them to be `myurl.org/mysite/route`.

I've tried changing `<base>` in index, also by using `--base-href` and `"baseHref": ...` in `angular.json`. These only seem to change the `<base>` and thus what url it listens on.

How can I keep the base url for the server to localhost without a base path, but construct routes base on some other base url?

A related issue is that the runtime/polyfills/main script doesn't load when running through proxy as as they are included as `<script src="runtime....js" type="module"></script>` which points too base path, i.e. `myurl.org/runtime....`, and doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The trick is to use all of the available url changing options:

```
ng s --prod \
    --public-host="http://myurl.org/mysite" 
    --deploy-url="mysite/" # prefixes the scripts tags
    --serve-path="" # makes sure to still listen on "/", not "/mysite"
    --base-href="mysite" # ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ probably path base
```

I'm far from 100% sure of what these do individually, but this is what finally worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try by running angular in a docker container with proxy configs to myurl.org and edit your host's config. For example:
127.0.0.1       myurl.org